# Excluding Source Directory in Maven

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to exclude a source directory in Maven?  I've searched on this topic and find plenty of discussion about excluding Resources, but very little on excluding Sources.

I have a repo with shared projects and several POM files.  Most coexist well, but one project has a conflict with one of the source directories and I need to exclude it only from that pom-file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    ...
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

        # I would like to add this but is not supported
        <excludeSourceDir>src/main/java/com/company/project/conflict-dir</excludeSourceDir>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

Edit 1:
Following the recommendations, I implemented a parent-pom and converted the existing pom files into modules -- each module referencing the parent (excellent instructions [here](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module)).  I also implemented a "maven-compiler-plugin" which allows one to `<exclude>` files.  Most projects compile and package correctly, except the original troublemaker project is still refusing to compile.  Still researching options.

Comment: Is this a multi-module project? Can you share a little bit more of the project setup?

Comment: Specifically w/o using the compiler plugin?

Comment: I may be doing this wrong, but I have several .pom files that operate independently of each other, but all within the project repo.  Each manages compiling/packaging a separate application using code drawn from shared code directories.  These seem like modules (using the Maven definition), but I'm not implementing them as such.  Should I be?

Comment: The original .pom file I inherited did not have a compiler plugin, so created new .pom files following that model.  Should I add a compiler plugin?

Comment: Consider doing this properly by moving into sub modules so there is no overlap.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours on this and after converting the code to use modules, I found two things:

- Instead of excluding files, I needed to specify the includes instead:

```
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
        <target>${maven.compiler.source}</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <includes>
            <include>com/company/my_module/*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

- The test code from the other modules was being run by default.  Yet this modules was not including the code for those tests.  I added  `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` to prevent that.

Comment: The use of `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` is trouble. Not sure how to resolve, but skipping tests is (usually) bad news.